# How to modify Netbeans maven project so that it creates "resources" folder automatically?

Tags: java, maven-3, netbeans-8

I am using NetBeans 8.0.2 and I use maven to create java projects through it. The problem is that the directory structure that gets created whenever I create a maven web project is `src/main/java` and `src/main/webapp` but it does not contain `src/main/resources`.

I have to create that every time manually. Is there a way to fix this problem so that "`resources`" folder gets created automatically every time I create a new project?

**Note:** I am not using NetBeans bundled Maven. I have explicitly downloaded Maven from apache and installed it in C:\ and then configured NetBeans editor to point to it.